# MySQL query hangs on `SELECT COUNT(*)`

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been playing around with MySQL and sqlalchemy to gather and store data. Over the the weekend I was collecting tweets at about 20,000 tweets/hour and placing them in a table `raw_tweets` indexed by their tweet id. I am expecting ~1,000,000 rows, but when I run

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from raw_tweets;
```

the query just hangs. I've waited a few minutes and still nothing. My knowledge of sql is fairly limited. Is it possible there is a lock on the table? Would that cause it to hang without giving rise to an error? How can I go about diagnosing/fixing this problem?

P.S. it looks like all my queries on that table are hanging.

Comment: There is apparently a lock on the table.

Comment: you may normalize your query like,SELECT COUNT(id) from raw_tweets;

Comment: Let's assume, your `id` field is a primary key. So as @SagarR sad, use `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM raw_teweets` Should be faster.

Comment: The performance difference between `COUNT(*)`, `COUNT(primary_key)` and `COUNT(1)` is marginal at best.  It does *NOT* explain what appears to be a `query hangs`.

Comment: I don't think speed is necessarily the problem. If @HLGEM is correct there is a lock on the table, but `SHOW OPEN TABLES` doesn't show any locks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably it doesn't hang but needs very much time to execute.

If the table engine is `InnoDB`, `SELECT COUNT(*)` must read all the rows from the table (in order to count them) and, if the database is under heavy use then the operation takes a lot of time.

This is documented in the [Limits on InnoDB Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html) page:

> InnoDB does not keep an internal count of rows in a table because concurrent transactions might “see” different numbers of rows at the same time. To process a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t` statement, InnoDB scans an index of the table, which takes some time if the index is not entirely in the buffer pool. To get a fast count, you have to use a counter table you create yourself and let your application update it according to the inserts and deletes it does. If an approximate row count is sufficient, `SHOW TABLE STATUS` can be used.

As explained above, if an approximate row count is enough for you then run:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE NAME = 'raw_tweets'
```

and look into the `Rows` column of the result.

Please note:

- the number of rows returned by `SHOW TABLE STATUS` is approximate; it can be off of the real value by several percents (the difference is higher when the table is small);
- the value returned by `SHOW TABLE STATUS` changes on each subsequent run, even if there is no write activity on the table.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. An approximate number is good enough as I was just verifying if data was collected. I wasn't aware of the InnoDB limitations.

Comment: If your table were using the old `MyISAM` engine then `SELECT COUNT(*)` would complete instantly because the engine keeps the value and updates it. It's probably too late to convert it now.

Answer (score 3):

you could run the following in another database connection (if you have sufficient rights to do so):

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

which might show all the queries/processes that are currently running on your database. In that list you might see if there are some locks set on a table

```
mysql> show full processlist;
+---------+------------+-----------------+------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| Id      | User       | Host            | db         | Command | Time | State | Info                  |
+---------+------------+-----------------+------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
|  121904 | user01     | localhost       | user_db    | Locked  |    0 |       | SELECT * FROM usr_tbl |
| 1186598 | root       | localhost       | NULL       | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show full processlist |
```

you should take a closer look at the `Command` and `Info` columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT row_count = SUM(row_count)
  FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('raw_tweets')
  AND index_id IN (0,1);
```

try this

Comment: This is a good response indeed, but could you explain why is it faster ? Thanks

Comment: @AxelGuilmin : thanks for your appreciation,first of all you wrote that you are already using indexed table so my solution partially fits for your problem,as we are working with index_id so its quite faster another thing you only need the count of rows and you are having primary key in your ID so,it's always best practice that use of Count(PRIMARYKEY FIELD) instead of use Count(*).